# Is there any Solution for my code problem in webbrowser to identify between Select tag and option

Tags: c#, html, webbrowser-control, sharepoint-discussion-board

I'm trying to Code webbrowser control to set information to an survey but I face problem to get the Address Survey ?

This is my sample in html Code:

```
    <label class="control-label required" for="select-address">Your Survey 
    Address is:</label>
     <select name="selectAddress" class="form-control" id="select-address" 
    data-SurveyValidation="true">
    <option selected="selected" disabled="" value="">Select from your 
    Registery:</option>
    <option id="survayAddress_8994716188695" value="8994716188695">
     PO Box A,&nbsp;Andover&nbsp;NY&nbsp;14806,&nbsp;United States
    </option>
    </select>
```

I tried this but not working!

```
                HtmlElementCollection col = Browser.Document.GetElementsByTagName("select");
                foreach (HtmlElement heItem in col)
                {

                    if (heItem.GetAttribute("name").Contains("selectAddress") == true)
                    {
                        heItem.SetAttribute("selectedIndex", "8994716188695"); // select value at #3
                        break; // incase of needed... 
                    }
                }
```

and this one !

```
    SetComboItem("survayAddress_8994716188695", "8994716188695");
    public void SetComboItem(string id, string value)
    {
        HtmlElement ee = this.Browser.Document.GetElementById(id);
        foreach (HtmlElement item in ee.Children)
        {
            if (item.OuterHtml.ToLower().IndexOf(value.ToLower()) >= 0)
            {
                item.SetAttribute("selected", "selected");
                item.InvokeMember("onChange");
            }
            else
            {
                item.SetAttribute("selected", "");
            }
        }

        ee = this.Browser.Document.GetElementById(id + "-input");
        ee.InnerText = value;
    }
```

Comment: no one ! can answer?! is it that difficulty ?